# iphone app minimum iOS required

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, submission

I am using Xcode 4 for my app. I have set my base SDK to 4.3 for both the Project and Target.

I would like to know which value in the setting dictates the "Requires iOS 3.0 or later" (for example) displayed in the app store.

Is it...

1. The base SDK set for the project and target set in 'Build Settings'
2. The 'Deployment Target' set in the 'Info' tab for the project.
3. The 'Deployment Target' set in the 'Summary' tab for the target.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is your project->Targets->your project->Search "iPhone OS Deployment Target"

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your Project -> Go to Get Info -> Go to Build tab -> Search "iOS Deployment Target" -> select your required min iOS.