# How to specify that I will only support ios7?

Tags: ios7

Basically no users with iOS 6 should be able to download the apps. That's it. I also want to use iOS 7 sdk.

How do I do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778230/iphone-app-minimum-ios-required

Answer (score 3):

1.Open your project in Xcode 5.0

2.Select project->Targets->your project->Search For IOS Deployment Target
  and change it to "7.0"

3.Also your Base SDK will be Latest ios(IOS 7.0) by default.(Check this in project->Targets->your project->Build Settings->Base SDK.)

Thats it.then nobody with ios 6 will be able to download your app :) cool..

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the iOS Deployment Target setting to target your build. (not to be confused with the Base SDK setting).

In Xcode 4 and up:

Use the Project Navigator to select your project and select the desired target from the "Targets" list on the left. You should see a setting under the "Info" tab named "Deployment Target". Set this to the version of iOS you wish to target.

To set the Base SDK, which is the version of the SDK you wish to use, switch to the "Build Settings" tab and look for or search for "Base SDK". Using this option you can choose specifically the Base SDK, though the default is "Latest" and will point to the latest supported SDK you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow simple below steps,

1. Specify ios target as "ios 7".
2. Also go to file inspector of xib to edit each class in xcode editor. Change below setting,

   ```
   Project deployment target = ios 7 and later        
   Vied as ios 7 and later.
   ```

Answer (score -3):

Put it on the main screenshot. "Only supports IOS 7".

Comment: Don't do this. Set the deployment target, and the App Store handles the rest.

Comment: you can put only works on android on the screenshot if you wanted, it wouldn't stop people from downloading it anyway.  Not a viable option.